# Apply a function to all buffers in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs23

Suppone that I want to apply `delete-trailing-whitespace` to all buffers in an Emacs session. How can I do that?

I have in this session many buffers. So instead to apply `M-x delete-trailing-whitespace`to manually each buffer, I need some way to make it automatically.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(defun delete-trailing-whitespace-each-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (mapc (lambda (buffer)
          (condition-case nil
              (with-current-buffer buffer
                (delete-trailing-whitespace))
            (buffer-read-only nil)))
        (buffer-list)))
```

It won't do anything on read-only buffers.

Answer (score 5):

`ibuffer` is another option.  You can quickly select the buffers you want (maybe by regexp), and press <kbd>E</kbd> to evaluate a form in each buffer.  This works for any form.